# how to deserialize json into dictionary c# and define the key?

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, jsonconvert

I have this class:

```
    public class Campaign{
     public   int campaign_id { get; set; }
     public   string campaign_name { get; set; }
     public   int representative_id { get; set; }}
```

And I can deserialize the `JSON` to a `List` like this:

```
 Campaigns = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Campaign>>(jsonstring);
```

But I want to access the items base on the campaign_name, how can I do that?
How to Deserialize it to a dictionary where the value will be the object and the key will be the campaign_name?
Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at the `.ToDictionary` extension method on `List<Campaign>` (though note you'll get an error if two entries have the same `campaign_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ToDictionary` method to convert your `List`. You can read more at [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=net-6.0):

```
var dict = Campaigns.ToDictionary(x => x.campaign_id);
```

Note that this will fail if an item exists in the list multiple times so you can `Distinct`:

```
var dict = Campaigns.Distinct().ToDictionary(x => x.campaign_id)
```

Comment: ok but how do I set the campaign_name as key?

Comment: @ILovePizza Check updated answer

Comment: Amazing! thank you :)))))

Answer (score 0):

For the Dictionary you can go with:

```
var dictionaryOfCampaign = Campaigns.ToDictionary(x => x.campaign_id, y => y);
```

If you don't want to use a dictionary you can filter your List using a linq query like this:

```
var filteredCampaign = Campaigns.Where(x => x.campaign_name.Equals("TEST"));
var filteredCampaign2 = Campaigns.Where(x => x.campaign_name.Contains("TEST"));
```

Remember to add in your using System.Linq